# Index was outside the bounds of the array while trying to start multiple threads

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this code which gives me an "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I don't know why is this happening because variable `i` should always be less than the length of array `bla` and therefore not cause this error.

```
private void buttonDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Thread> t = new List<Thread>();

    string[] bla = textBoxBla.Lines;

    for (int i = 0; i < bla.Length; i++)
    {
        t.Add(new Thread (() => some_thread_funmction(bla[i])));
        t[i].Start();
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this and why is this happening. Thanks!

Comment: What are the contents of bla?

Comment: You need to make a copy of `i` and pass the copy to the thread function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Closures** are your problem here.

Basically, instead of grabbing the value when you create the lambda (in the loop), it grabs it when it needs it. And computers are so fast that by the time that happens, it's already out of the loop. And the value's 3.
Here's an example (don't run it yet):

```
private void buttonDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Thread> t = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        t.Add(new Thread (() => Console.Write(i)));
        t[i].Start();
    }
}
```

Think about what you'd expect the result to be. Would it be `012` you're thinking?

Now run it.

The result will be `333`.

Here's some modified code that'll fix it:

```
private void buttonDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Thread> t = new List<Thread>();
    string[] bla = textBoxBla.Lines;
    for (int i = 0; i < bla.Length; i++)
    {
        int y = i; 
        //note the line above, that's where I make the int that the lambda has to grab
        t.Add(new Thread (() => some_thread_funmction(bla[y]))); 
        //note that I don't use i there, I use y.
        t[i].Start();
    }
}
```

Now it'll work fine. This time the value goes out of scope when the loop finishes, so the lambda has no choice but to take it before the loop finishes. That will get you your expected result, and no exception.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I'll set your answer as the best in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is a race condition.  Your `for` loop is completing prior to the threads actually starting.  So by the time the threads actually start the value of `i` is outside of the bounds of the array.

Try copying the index value and pass in the copy instead.

```
private void buttonDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Thread> t = new List<Thread>();

    string[] bla = textBoxBla.Lines;

    for (int i = 0; i < bla.Length; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        t.Add(new Thread (() => some_thread_funmction(bla[index])));
        t[i].Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response also :)