# C# index out of range, multi thread, Logs

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, indexing

I am trying to grab logs from windows. To make it faster I look for the days where logs are and then for that range of those days I open one thread per day to load it fast. In function `work1` the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array" appears. If I make the job in only one thread it works fine but it is very very slow.

I tried to use the information from 
"[Index was outside the bounds of the array while trying to start multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843510/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-while-trying-to-start-multiple-threads)"
but it does not work.

I think the problem is in IEnumerable when it is loaded, like it is not loaded in time when the loop is started.

Sorry for my english, i am from Uzbekistan.

```
var result = from EventLogEntry elog in aLog.Entries
             orderby elog.TimeGenerated
             select elog.TimeGenerated;
DateTime OLDentry = result.First();
DateTime NEWentry = result.Last();
DTN.Add(result.First());
foreach (var dtn in result) {
    if (dtn.Year != DTN.Last().Year | 
        dtn.Month != DTN.Last().Month |
        dtn.Day != DTN.Last().Day
    ) {
        DTN.Add(dtn);
    }
}
List<Thread> t = new List<Thread>();
int i = 0;
foreach (DateTime day in DTN) {
    DateTime yad = day;
    var test = from EventLogEntry elog in aLog.Entries
               where (elog.TimeGenerated.Year == day.Year) &&
                     (elog.TimeGenerated.Month == day.Month) &&
                     (elog.TimeGenerated.Day == day.Day)
               select elog;
    var tt2 = test.ToArray();
    t.Add(new Thread(() => work1(tt2)));
    t[i].Start();
    i++;
}

static void work1(IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> b)  {
    var z = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < z.Count(); i++) {
        Console.Write(z + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you pinpoint where that error is thrown from? Also, you're printing `z` to the console.. which is a reference to an `IEnumerable` .. I'm going to assume that's not what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `var tt2 = test;` with `var tt2 = test.ToArray();`

The error is a mistake you do numerous times in your code: you are enumerating over a the data countless times. Calling `.Count()` enumerates the data again, and in this case the data ends up conflicting with cached values inside the `EventLogEntry` enumerator.

LINQ does not return a data set. It returns a query. A variable of type `IEnumerable<T>` may return different values every time you call `Count()`, `First()` or `Last()`. Calling `.ToArray()` makes C# retrieve the result and store it in an array.

You should generally just enumerate an `IEnumerable<T>` once.